# Laravel 5.4 migrate key is too long error

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, mysql-5.7

when I run migrate command with laravel 5.4 I get an error "specific key was too long", I searched and found many people also face this error. The common is add `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` in `AppServiceProvider.php`. But the doc https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error says it is for those mysql version older than 5.7.7. But my version is 5.7.14(`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.14, for Win64 (x86_64)`), and I already set mysql default charset to utf8mb4(`show variables like "%char%"`):

[image]

So I think I do not need to change anything but I still get the problem. It makes me confused. Who can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an unique composite key defined in your migration?

Answer (score 1):

1. Set `innodb_file_format=Barracuda`
2. Set `innodb_large_prefix=1`
3. Set `innodb_default_row_format=dynamic`

Step 1 (innodb_file_format) and 2 (innodb_large_prefix) works on older Mysql versions, including MariaDB. I do not know the lower version bounds for these. [Mysql 5.7.7 changed the defaults](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-7.html) for these settings, but they existed earlier.

Step 3 (innodb_default_row_format) requires Mysql 5.7.9 or newer.

For the sake of documentation; a workaround if you're missing the innodb_default_row_format setting is to use the engine `innodb row_format=dynamic`. This abuses the fact that Laravel appends this to the CREATE TABLE statement without any escaping, resulting in `... ENGINE=innodb row_format=dynamic`.

[Laravel 5.2.14 introduced the ability to specify the engine](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/dbcf0ab7a8e4b964bcd690e14f82726b97cb378f) in `config/database.php`. If you're on an older version you have to specify this in every migration that creates a table. `$table->engine = 'innodb row_format=dynamic';`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make sure you have set `innodb_large_prefix` to `On`. According to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix) it should be default in Mysql >= 5.7.7 but maybe you use non-standard settings.

Answer (score 0):

go to config/database.php
set this 'engine'=>innodb.

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => innodb,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```